# I separated arms from the torso of a model, how can I seamlessly attach them again?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

So I ended up separating the arms from the torso of this model to make it easier to rig. I just got into blender today and I don't know how to seamlessly join them back together with the torso again without disturbing the weights of the model. How can I join these edges back together?

[image: Gaps between arm and torso]

Answer (score 1):

You could just snap vertex and then merge them by distance (or remove double vertices)
[image]

Comment: Thanks! What would be the hotkeys for these actions?

Comment: I dont know this hotkey, but just enable it, press G to move the vertex and move the mouse where you want to snap (To turn on snapping look my answer, I edited it)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help! It's really gotten me through my first major roadblock :)

Comment: Dont worry :D, good luck with your model

Comment: Holding Ctrl down enables snapping temporarily. There is a lesser known feature that if you snap to a point, release Ctrl and press A while still hovering over that point and then press Ctrl down again it will now lock to the first vertex and snap to the average of it and whatever else you snap to. You can keep adding snap points with A or add more weight to one point if you hit A multiple times over it, so if you hit A 2 times on one and then snap to another point it will be 1/3 of the distance between both of them.

Comment: Shift + Tab is the default hotkey for toggling snap in v2.8x